# Add max value everyday at midnight

Tags: javascript

The value of i should increment to 500 in intervals of 5 seconds. But I need the previous day's total to be added to the following day. For simplicity now, I just need to add the max value prior to the start of the daily incrementing of i. However i is initializing at 0 for the incrementing and will reset regardless of max being added to it.

What is the best way to go about this?
Here's my code so far.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    var div = document.getElementById('count');
    var i = 0; 
    var count = 0;
    var max = 500;
    var d = new Date();
    // set d to midnight
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    d.setMonth(0);
    d.setDate(1);
    d.setFullYear(2017);
     var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
     var today = new Date().getTime();  
     var numberofdays = Math.round((today - d.getTime()) / one_day);


   function isPastMidnight() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      if ((currentTime - d.getTime()) > 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      } 
    }
    function updateCount() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      if (!isPastMidnight()) {
       document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Check back January 1, 2017.";
      }


     if (isPastMidnight())   {
      if (numberofdays > 0 && today == d.getHours)   {      
        addmax();

        }
      }
     if (isPastMidnight() && i < max) {
        i = Math.floor((currentTime - d.getTime() ) / 5000);
        if (i > max) i = max; 
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = i;
      }
        if (i >= max) {
        // Stop executing myself ("interval" is declared in global scope, so accessible from here)
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    updateCount();
    var interval = setInterval(updateCount, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're actual question is in more detail?

Comment: I'm making a counter that will increment each day by 1 every 5 seconds until the number (i) hits 500.

Comment: The 500 each day needs to be added to the next days incrementing. So on jan. 2, i should no longer be 0 but 500 since  the previous day's 500 is a part of it. 3rd day i will begin at 1000, etc, each day incrementing by 1 til the daily max hits 500

Comment: Right now i increments beautifully:) But what is the best way to make sure the actual total gets carried over?

Comment: So you are not sure, if you're implementation is really solid and will always work?

Comment: The incrementing works. But i need to add max variable to increase the number that will be incremented each day.

Comment: So you need the correct initial values for `i`? Why don't you set `i=500*numberofdays`. However, Id recommend, you use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round` on `numberofdays`

Comment: If i change the value of i like that, it wont act like a counter anymore.

Comment: I mean just once in the beginnig, when the page loads. Or are you planning to make it run all day long 24/7? Then you might want to in the begining add a Timeout till next midnight and then restart the counter with a offset of 500. Donno if im getting you right though

Comment: Oh before the for loop?

Comment: I did i=max * numberofdays; but that returned a blank page

Comment: I know that:) Thats why I set my laptop date and time to jan. 1:)

Comment: `today == d.getHours` will never be true, since *d.getHours* is a function object. Even if you change it to `d.getHours()`, it will only be true if *today* is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 since you're comparing the current time value to 0 (it's set to 0 earlier with `d.setHours(0,0,0,0)`).

Comment: 500 x 5 is 2,500 seconds, which is only 41 minutes and 40 seconds. The counter will reach its maximum at 00:41:40 each day until the next day.

Comment: I will increase the interval when the testing is complete to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of says since 1 January and multiply by 500, then the number of 5 second (or whatever) increments up to 500 and add it to the count. There are many questions about how to count days between dates and do mathematics on the current time value.

Your code seems overly complex, if you don't want to start the counter until 1 Jan 2017 then just test if the date is before then.

```js
/* Return number of whole days between dates. Sets
** time to 00:00:00 so only measures whole days.
** @param {Date} d0 - start date
** @param {Date} d1 - end date
** @returns {number} whole days between dates
*/
function daysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {
  var d0 = new Date(+startDate);
  var d1 = new Date(+endDate);
  return Math.round((d1.setHours(0,0,0,0) - d0.setHours(0,0,0,0)) / 8.64e7);
}

/* Return a value that is 500 * the number of days since 1 Jan of the current year
** + 1 for each interval since 00:00:00 on the current day
** @param {Date} date
** @returns {number}
*/
function getCurrentCount(date) {
  // Don't run before 1 Jan 2017
  if (date < new Date(2017,0,1)) return 'Too early...';

  // Get count for whole days since 1 Jan 2017
  var count = 500 * daysBetweenDates(new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0), date);

  // Find milliseconds since midnight at start of day
  var dayPart = date - new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0)

  // Add increments
  var increment = 5000;
  dayPart = Math.floor(dayPart % 8.64e7 / increment);

  // Increment by dayPart if less than 500, or 500 otherwise
  count += dayPart > 500? 500 : dayPart;

  return count;
}

// Some tests
[new Date(),              // Now
 new Date(2017,0,1,0,30), // 2017-01-01 00:30:00
 new Date(2017,5,23,0,30) // 2017-06-23 00:30:00
].forEach(function(d) { 
  console.log('Count for ' + d.toString() + 'is: ' + getCurrentCount(d));
});
```

Comment: I actually just got it working 5 minutes ago before seeing this. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Multiplied days by max variable and added it to i in a math statement. So the first day incremented starting at 0 and not 500, I put it into an if statement that will only allow it to execute if days are greater than 0.
Thanks again!